# How to assign alias to variable declared in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have declared one variable in SQL Server:

```
declare @InsuredRaceEthnicId int
```

And assigning value to it like this:

```
select @InsuredRaceEthnicId = MAX(InsuredRaceEthnicId) 
from dbo.InsuredRaceEthnic with (nolock)
```

It's giving me value with no column name but I need a column name.

Comment: Are you trying to set the variable or return the `MAX()`?

Comment: Yes i am trying to get latest inserted identity column value

Comment: Why would an integer have a column name?

Comment: In my vb code i am trying to do column.value. If i don't have column it gives me an error.

Comment: We'd probably need to see a bit of the vb code to proceed...

Comment: What is the actual query you are running in your VB code?

Comment: Why don't you forget the sql server variable altogether and run a query with an alias?

Answer (score 1):

You can alias a variable the same way you'd alias a column:

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(50) = '1222'
SELECT @test AS Test
```

Your `SELECT` statement shouldn't be returning anything, it's just setting the value of the variable, you could subsequently `SELECT`/`PRINT` the variable if so desired.